# passing function variable value to new variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to pass value of xyz from function to a new var abc, but its not working.
I tried like abc="'"+xyz+"'"; (Not working)
If I try like abc='anything'; it works and i can use abc value to new function in document.ready function.
I want dynamically generated value of xyz, for abc with single quotes.
With all your suggestion I am updating the code, i tried all the way... but dont know why abc is not catching the value of xyz or newcityval();
Also I have one line script above the code, where default value of abc is specified. Now when city value changes city_val gets updated and same i check using alert function.
Also for abc if i put any value manually like abc='anything'; and alert it work fine.
But using all the suggesstions its not working. 
I also declared global vars for both xyz and abc.
updated code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>abc = 'any value';</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var xyz;
var abc;
function newcityval(){  
    xyz = $("#city").val();
    document.getElementById('city_val').value=xyz;
    return alert("'"+xyz+"'");

}

abc=newcityval();
if(abc!='')
{
alert("value is "+abc);
}
else
{
    alert('No value');
}

</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: `var abc = newcityval()`?

Comment: `abc="'"+xyz+"'";` isn't working because `xyz` hasn't been declared in that scope. Try: `abc=newcityval();` I'm guessing that is more what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the returned value of your function use:

```
abc = newcityval();
```

In `abc="'"+xyz+"'";` the xyz is an undefined variable. because you define your xyz variable inside your function.

---

Update:

set script like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function newcityval(){
        xyz = $("#city").val();
        document.getElementById('city_val').value=xyz;
        return "'"+xyz+"'";
    }

    function run()
    {
        abc=newcityval();
        if(abc!='')
        {
            alert("value is "+abc);
        }
        else
        {
            alert('No value');
        }
    }
</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<input id="city" />
<input id="city_val" />
<button onclick="run()">do</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, your code helped me to update my code with some changes and things are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try abc = "'" + newcityval() + "'"

You are declaring xyz local to the newcityval function so it is unavailable outside.

Answer (score 0):

you need to type

```
var abc = newcityval();
```

xyz is a variable inside the scope of newcityval, which means it's not available when you are trying to assign it to abc.